# Changing filed to ObjectID MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have a collection that contains around 5000 documents. In each document there is field BrandID that I would like to change from string to MongoDB ObjectID. I have tried following shell command but it only updates first document. I dont get any error at all.

```
db.getCollection('SGProductRepository').find({ BrandID: {$ne : ""}}).forEach(function(obj) {    
    obj.BrandID = new ObjectId(obj.BrandID);
db.getCollection('SGProductRepository').save(obj);    
})
```

Any idea why it is not working. I am using RoboMongo as an editor.
Thanks

Comment: Well... It is so weird: `{ BrandID: {$eq : ""}}`. It means there many objects with empty BrandID? If so, empty string cannot be a valid object id (even though any errors is shown )

Comment: sorry I used not equal , just in the code snippet above as I was trying few thing I copied equal. Yes there are many blank values thats why I am using not equal.